Unknown value in PowerShell Custom Object
I'm a beginner to PowerShell and Active Directory. I have grabbed below PowerShell script from the internet, intending to get all AD Users of Users type (in the Organization) and his all AD Groups he is part of. Am iterating AD users in outer loop with property "Name" as filter and his AD group in nested loop (code below).
Class CustomAdInfo 
{
    $UserName
    $Group
    $Email
}
$users_with_starting_letter = @('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z')
foreach ( $node in $users_with_starting_letter )
{
 $filter = 'Name -like "' + $node + '*"'
 $customObjects = 
    foreach($user in $filter)
    {
        $adUserObj = Get-ADUser -Filter $user -properties SamAccountName,memberOf,EmailAddress -ResultPageSize 256 -SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=ab,DC=cd"
        $groups = $adUserObj.MemberOf | Get-ADgroup
        foreach($group in $groups)
        {
            New-Object -TypeName CustomAdInfo -Property @{
                UserName = $adUserObj.SamAccountName
                Group = $group
                Email = $adUserObj.EmailAddress
                
            }
        }
    }
    $customObjects | Select-Object -Property Username,group,Email | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\Members_and_Groups.csv' -Append
}

The Output (showing some samples here) I received  is:
"System.Object[]","CN=group1,CN=Users,DC=ab,DC=cd","System.Object[]"
"System.Object[]","CN=group2,CN=Users,DC=ab,DC=cd","System.Object[]"

Expecting SamAccountName and EmailAddress of a AD User in column 1 and 3 respectively, but received some unknown value "System.Object[]". What am I missing?
Thank you a lot for the response!!

Do you really have the @{ in the next line or is it in the same line as -Property ? If so, that's a typo, @{ must be in the same line as the New-Object statement. PowerShell is not great for Allman coding style, would advise against it for this language.

I'm assuming that @Santiago's analysis is correct, and have linked to a relevant duplicate. Let us know if the syntax turned out not to be the problem, after all.

Another option is that $filter = 'Name -like "' + $node + '*"' matches multiple user accounts, in which case UserName = $adUserObj.SamAccountName would return an array of property values (search “Powershell member-access enumeration” for how that works), which serialises to the string System.Object[].

Thank you for the response @SantiagoSquarzon. In the actual PowerShell script am executing, it's in the same line of New-Object. It's a typo in this forum I made, corrected it now here.

Thank you @mclayton. I will search “Powershell member-access enumeration” and try it again.

The issue with your code is due to a missing loop on $adUserObj, you're filtering for all users starting with a letter, i.e.: Name -like 'a*', a filter like this one will surely return more than a single user.
To fix this but also to make your code more readable I'd suggest creating the filters first and then query the users.
Class CustomAdInfo {
    $UserName
    $Group
    $Email
}

[char[]] ([char] 'a'..[char] 'z') | ForEach-Object {
    $getADUserSplat = @{
        Filter         = "Name -like '$_*'"
        Properties     = 'SamAccountName', 'memberOf', 'EmailAddress'
        ResultPageSize = 256
        SearchBase     = 'CN=Users,DC=ab,DC=cd'
    }
    foreach ($user in Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat) {
        foreach ($group in $user.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup) {
            [CustomAdInfo]@{
                UserName = $user.SamAccountName
                Group    = $group.Name # <= You need to choose an attribute here
                Email    = $user.EmailAddress
            }
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\Members_and_Groups.csv'


@SandeepKumar try the update

@SandeepKumar ask a new question, ill show you. This answer is for your initial question

Thank you a lot @Santiago Squarzon for the reply!! You are my saviour!! I tested above PowerShell script, range specified above [char] 'a'..[char] 'z' is actually returning ASCII values of the range. So I modified range to [char[]]([char]'y'..[char]'z') , which received character values only.

We actually have expression for few properties. Existing Code as
$ad_users = Get-ADUser -Filter $Filter  -Property EmployeeID,Manager,uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType -ResultPageSize 256 -SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=ab,DC=cd"
$ad_users | Select-Object -Property EmployeeID,@{Name="Manager";Expression={$_.Manager -replace '^CN=|,.*$'}},@{Name="uht_IdentityManagement_AccountType";Expression={$_."uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType"}}
How to have these expressions in above code, i.e., while assigning values to class properties? Something like Manager=$user.Manager.replace_junk_characters

@SandeepKumar ask in a new question. This answer is for the question being asked

Sure @Santiago Squarzon!!
